# How to automatically add a worksheet from a template when a cell is filled out on a master sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, templates, worksheet

I have an excel workbook with two worksheets "Master" and "Template"
I want to copy "template" once a cell, from range `A2:A20`, in worksheet "Master" is filled out and name a new worksheet with `A2:20` value.
I would like to copy value from Master sheet of two cells, into newly created worksheet (from master cells `A2:B2` to new sheet (with a name `A2`) to cells `D1:D2`).
I want to do that for each cells `A2:A20` that are filled out, so that it would not create a new worksheet for cells from `A2:A20` that are empty.

So if I would have `A2`, `A4`, and `A5` filled out I would get 3 new worksheet, like template worksheet, with names from `A2`, `A4` and `A5`. In first new sheet `A2:B2` from master, would be copied to `D1:D2`. In second new sheet `A4:B4`, would be copied to `D1:D2` and on the third new worksheet `A5:B5` would be copied to `D1:D2`

I would like to have this done, once excel is open, and if once done, not to repeat it

is this possible?

much appreciate any help

```
Sub CreateAndNameWorksheets()

    Dim c As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each c In Sheets("Master").Range("A2:A20")

        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

        With c

            ActiveSheet.Name = .Value

           .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                "'" & .Text & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=.Text

        End With

    Next c

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in the Workbook module of the Excel file.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    With Worksheets("Master")

        'check if sheet creation process has happened already
        If .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).Value = "" Then

            Dim c As Range

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            For Each c In .Range("A2:A20")

                Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

                With c

                    ActiveSheet.Name = .Value

                    .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                         "'" & .Text & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=.Text

                End With

            Next c

            .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).Value = "created" 'mark cell as created so it skips next time and each time after

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

ThisWorkbook class module:

[image]

Comment: Before `next c` , there should be something similar to this for the answer to be complete: `ActiveSheet.Range("D1:D2") = .Range(.Cells(c.Row, 1), .Cells(c.Row, 2)).Value`

Comment: Hi, I'm getting End with error: End with without with

Comment: very sorry @KasiaKate - it's fixed now